# How to change tag types with jQuery

Tags: jquery

So I have a HTML editor (WYSIWYG editor) on my site that really isn't responding the way it should be.

Basically, it is loading all my sections within a `fieldset` wrapper, which is fantastic, but then it also creates all sections as a `fieldset`. I need to breakdown this section and convert it to a description list, `dl`.

**Here is what it is currently like:**

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Our Services</legend>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Some title here</legend>
        <p>Some long text here...</p>
        <p>Some long text here...</p>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Some title here</legend>
        <p>Some long text here...</p>
        <p>Some long text here...</p>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Some title here</legend>
        <p>Some long text here...</p>
        <p>Some long text here...</p>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Some title here</legend>
        <p>Some long text here...</p>
        <p>Some long text here...</p>
    </fieldset>
</fieldset>
```

**Here is what the converted version should be like:**

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Our Services</legend>
    <dl>
        <dt>Some title here</dt>
        <dd><p>Some long text here...<p></dd>

        <dt>Some title here</dt>
        <dd><p>Some long text here...<p></dd>

        <dt>Some title here</dt>
        <dd><p>Some long text here...<p></dd>

        <dt>Some title here</dt>
        <dd><p>Some long text here...<p></dd>
    </dl>
</fieldset>
```

I know I need to use functions like `replaceWith` and `wrap`, although I am just not to sure how to approach this.

The function that is created will be run when the document is ready and will convert everything that way. I no it is not ideal, but hey, it'll do.

I am not asking anyone to write me a huge chunk of code, I am mainly asking for guidance on how to approach this.

Comment: what does this title have to do with this question ?

Comment: there are `<p>Some long text here...</p>
        <p>Some long text here...</p>` in the source but the desired output you have `<dd><p>Some text here<p></dd>`

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli - Sorry, title was from a previous post. Changing now.

Comment: What do you mean you have _"a HTML editor on"_ your site?

Comment: @Sparky - Hard to explain, but my clients can change content via a WYSIWYG editor.

Comment: You mean the website contains a CMS?  If you can't explain that...

Comment: @ArunPJohny - Sorry, cleaned everything up. Friday morning, brains not working properly.

Comment: @Sparky - Not necessarily. It is a very small CMS that we have created.

Comment: So why not fix the root cause instead of monkeying with the DOM after the fact?

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/DuzTd/1/

Comment: @Sparky - Almost impossible since the editor was not created by us, and would take days of messing around to find the root of the problem. We need to apply a fix now while we look for the source of the problem.

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/DuzTd/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an ideal solution I would recommend fixing the root cause, ie the editor.

If that is not possible try

```
var $items = $('fieldset fieldset').wrap('<dl />').contents().unwrap().parent();
$items.find('legend').wrap('<dt />').contents().unwrap();
$items.each(function () {
    $(this).find('p').wrapAll('<dd />');
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/DuzTd/), Or [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/DuzTd/3/)

Answer (score 1):

A solution for the specifically described problem is

```
var fieldset = $('fieldset fieldset');

fieldset.wrapAll('<dl>').find('legend').wrapInner('<dt>').children().unwrap()
fieldset.each(function(){
    $(this).find('p').wrapAll('<dd>');
}).children().unwrap();
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/YD5n5/